# using a static library featuring <mutex> in a CLR library

Tags: c++, c++-cli, clr

I have a utility library written in c++ that I use in many of my projects.

I wanted to create a partial wrapper for it in c++/CLI to bring some of its features to a vb.net project of mine but immediately ran into a problem -

```
<mutex> is not supported when compiling with /clr or /clr:pure.
```

And I can't cut out the things using mutex either since the ria logging utility I have there is the main thing I want this wrapper for and it relies heavily on mutex.

So.. is there any way around this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot "hide" the C++ headers that are illegal in CLR (mutex, atomic, ...) by mean of a wrapper C++ class/code or simple forward declarations,

the only other way I succeeded in something very similar is by creating an Interop assembly with:
 - an unmanaged C++ "layer" whose only purpose is to insulate the "real" C++ code (containing mutex, atomic and anything illegal in CLR)
 - a managed C++ "layer" that uses the unmanaged layer, and exposed its API/services to the .NET world.

Ugly, heavy to maintain and error-prone as it can be, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Only extern "C" exported functions can be loaded from native DLL's to /clr:pure.
You have to wrap your functionality by global C-Style functions. These you can export as DLL and import in a /CLR App or Lib.
Go to https://www.codeproject.com and search for 'Console Output General For All Executables'. There is an Example where you can see the concrete syntax.
Good Luck